# How to make the JFXTextArea extendes horizontally and vertically?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to print my file content to the TextArea, but its scroll up and down only.
So if the line too long in horizontal it will make a new line not extend the line.
  [This is the file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQJEC.png)
and this id how [it printed in the Text Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4lsC.png).
This is my Code:

```
try {
        out.setFont(Font.font("monospaced",16));
        InputStream inputstream = new FileInputStream("output.txt");
        int data = inputstream.read();
        while(data != -1) {
            char aChar = (char) data;
            out.appendText(String.valueOf(aChar));
            System.out.print(aChar);
            data = inputstream.read();

        }
        inputstream.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
```

Comment: You're refering to `JFXTextArea`, correct? `TextArea` does not have this issue, unless you set the `wrapText` property to `true`.

Comment: Thank you very much <3
@fabian